# How to replace <e9> by é in vim

Tags: search, vim, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I want to search and replace "<*e9*>" by "é".

> :%s/<*e9*>/é/g

Doesn't works but <*e9*> seems vim special char

> / ctrl+v xe9

find only the correct "é" but not "<*e9*>"

If i'm on <*e9*> and i type :ascii i've got this result:

> <é> 233, Hexa 00e9, Octal 351

If i'm on "é" and i type :ascii i've got this result:

> <é> 233, Hexa 00e9, Octal 351

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your text already contains the proper `é` character (as shown by the `:ascii` command), it's just that Vim doesn't display it like that. (You can verify with another text lister / editor.)

How characters are displayed is governed by the `'isprint'` option. Its help says:

> When 'encoding' is a Unicode one, illegal bytes from 128 to 255 are
>     displayed as `<xx>`, with the hexadecimal value of the byte.

So, assuming you haven't change the 'isprint' value, you likely have an issue with the detection of the encoding. Check

```
:set encoding? fileencodings? fileencoding?
```

and correct.

Comment: encoding=utf-8
  fileencodings=utf-8
  fileencoding=

Comment: @ChoiZ: Your file is probably encoded as latin1 (aka iso-8859-1, or some other encoding where 0xE9 is é, like cp1252), but your `fileencodings` setting causes it to always be loaded as utf-8 (where the byte 0xE9 by itself is invalid), thus Vim shows the character in the `<xx>` format. You can load the file as latin1 with `:e ++enc=latin1`. If you want to convert it to UTF-8, then follow it up with `:set fenc=utf-8|w` (the character will be written as two bytes: 0xC3 0xA9).

Comment: Great answer @ChrisJohnsen! can i specify to convert some lines to latin1? And leave the other in utf8?

Comment: @ChoiZ: If you have *iconv* (e.g. you are on a Unixy system), then you can probably use (e.g.) `:4,5!iconv -f latin1 -t utf-8` to convert lines 4 and 5 (or make a visual selection, and type `:!iconv `…; the `'<,'>` range (denoting the selection) will automatically be used). Just make sure that UTF-8 is the effective encoding: `fenc=utf-8` or that `fenc=` and `enc=utf-8` (empty `fenc` defaults `enc`). If you do not have iconv, then you can probably do `:e ++enc=latin1`, yank the latin1 lines into a register, then `:e` (i.e. re-edit as UTF-8) and paste them back, replacing the originals.

Comment: @ChrisJohnsen Thanks to you i learn ++enc in vim and it's awesome.
I try to yank the latin1 into a register.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK `<e9>` is a single character somehow corrupted with encoding conversions.

At command mode, when your cursor is on `<e9>` give command `yl`. This will yank the character to buffer. Then search for the yanked character by giving command `/<C-R>-` (This involves going to search mode, pressing `CTRL+R` and pressing `-`.) Your search should find all the `<e9>` chars in text. Finally do a substitution by using the last search result:

```
%s//é/g
```

Comment: Normally it should work,but this may not be the case for an illegal character.

Comment: Try again with `<C-R>"`, i.e. `CTRL-R` followed by `"`. The hyphen register `-` isn't the right one.

Comment: It's works with <C-R>" instead of -
But it's search «é» instead of <e9>